# AsyncEnumerator usage example

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Just getting my hands on AsyncEnumerator library and not sure what piece I am missing.
I trying to get to run [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721613.aspx) provided by the library author himself but have no clue what does the "Execute" in the line:

```
ae.Execute(ProcessAllAndEachOps(ae, urls));
```

method refer to.
Can anybody give me some clues?

UPDATE:
I managed to get it running by making a few changes which are already included in the code below. The credit goes to Peter for noticing that the Execute() method of the AsyncEnumerator object is obsolete and should be replaced with some helper function.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Wintellect.Threading.AsyncProgModel;


public static class AsyncEnumeratorPatterns {

    private static void Execute(AsyncEnumerator ae, IEnumerator<Int32> enumerator){
                    ae.EndExecute(ae.BeginExecute(enumerator, null));
    }

      public static void Main() {
        String[] urls = new String[] { 
          "http://Wintellect.com/", 
          "http://1.1.1.1/",   // Demonstrates error recovery
          "http://www.Devscovery.com/" 
        };

        // Demonstrate process
        AsyncEnumerator ae = new AsyncEnumerator();
        Execute(ae, ProcessAllAndEachOps(ae, urls));
      }

      private static IEnumerator<Int32> ProcessAllAndEachOps(
           AsyncEnumerator ae, String[] urls) {
        Int32 numOps = urls.Length;

        // Issue all the asynchronous operation(s) so they run concurrently
        for (Int32 n = 0; n < numOps; n++) {
          WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(urls[n]);
          wr.BeginGetResponse(ae.End(), wr);
        }

        // Have AsyncEnumerator wait until ALL operations complete
        yield return numOps;

        Console.WriteLine("All the operations completed:");
        for (Int32 n = 0; n < numOps; n++) {
          ProcessCompletedWebRequest(ae.DequeueAsyncResult());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(); // *** Blank line between demos ***

        // Issue all the asynchronous operation(s) so they run concurrently
        for (Int32 n = 0; n < numOps; n++) {
          WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(urls[n]);
          wr.BeginGetResponse(ae.End(), wr);
        }

        for (Int32 n = 0; n < numOps; n++) {
          // Have AsyncEnumerator wait until EACH operation completes
          yield return 1;

          Console.WriteLine("An operation completed:");
          ProcessCompletedWebRequest(ae.DequeueAsyncResult());
        }
      }

      private static void ProcessCompletedWebRequest(IAsyncResult ar) {
        WebRequest wr = (WebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
        try {
          Console.Write("   Uri=" + wr.RequestUri + "    ");
          using (WebResponse response = wr.EndGetResponse(ar)) {
            Console.WriteLine("ContentLength=" + response.ContentLength);
          }
        }
        catch (WebException e) {
          Console.WriteLine("WebException=" + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from the given piece of code, it seems it just starts the asyncenumeration process.

Comment: Well, yes it does start the execution but where is it defined?

Comment: Right-click on it and choose "Go to definition". That should give you a hint as to where the method is defined.

Comment: @Jodrell
I can only see a method called BeginExecute on the AsyncEnumerator object.

Comment: I don't see how `AsyncEnumerator.Execute` can perform the operation asynchronously for each url

Comment: @Charlie Kilian
That's the whole point of my question: in the examples given by the author he mentioned that Execute is a helper function but is defined nowhere. He only gives the method signature.

Comment: Ahh, my apologies, I misunderstood the question. I thought the `Execute()` method was a part of the AsyncEnumerator library. It might not hurt to update the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @CharlieKilian
It seems to me that the current title is the most relevant unless you have some other thoughts. Feel free to change it.

Comment: AsyncEnumerator is part of the Power Threading Library.  I suggest you download it first.  See http://www1.wintellect.com/resources/Details/76

Comment: @Peter Ritchie
Well, No. I have not asked where I could download the library from. If you read my post again you can see at the top that I have the Wintellect library properly referenced, but thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Then I'm not clear why you're asking this question if you've already downloaded the library.  It details in there (the overview) that Execute has been obsoleted but is equivalent of `ae.EndExecute(ae.BeginExecute(…))`

Comment: Bingo! That's the answer I have been looking for. It's a shame that these MDSN articles don't event mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, the Execute method was deprecated a while ago and is now gone completely, that MSDN example is quite old.

That method slightly defeated the point of the AsyncEnumerator class, as the thread making the call will run the iterator until the first yield and then block until the iterator has finished processing.

So its maybe more clear to replace it with:

```
var asyncResult = ae.BeginExecute(ProcessAllAndEachOps(ae, urls), null);
asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
ae.EndExecute(asyncResult);
```

Which looks a little bit more like making regular APM calls from within an AsyncEnumerator iterator and makes the blocking more explicit.